# Why does ng-messages for form validation not work when using $rollbackViewValue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-validation

I have a form using ng-messages for form validation error messages. Im also using the new ng-model-options with $rollbackViewValue to rollback all changes to the form. Problem is ng-mesages will not work if I use the rollbackViewValue on the form.

I really like this new function in angular1.3 using ng-model-options to reset a form as I have not found anything that works as well as $rollbackViewValue()

Heres is the code and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/74jEiWfRCltLDCIuAIgR)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="App">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="formCrtl as vm">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
        <form name="form" novalidate="novalidate" role="form"
              data-ng-submit="vm.submit()"
              data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" >
            <!---->
            <div class="form-group"  data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.fname.$invalid && form.fname.$touched }">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="vm.names.fname">
                <div data-ng-if="form.fname.$touched" data-ng-messages="form.fname.$error">
                    <span class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lname.$invalid && form.lname.$touched }">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="vm.names.lname">
                <div data-ng-if="form.lname.$touched" data-ng-messages="form.lname.$error">
                    <span class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 btn-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="form.$rollbackViewValue()">reset</button>
                <!---->
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

controller

```
var App = angular.module("App", ['App', 'ngMessages']);
App.controller('formCrtl',function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.names = {
        fname: "Albert",
        lname: "Capone"
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i removed my answer. Apparently rollback does not work with submit event because seems like there is some issue when we have validation errors, in such cases it updated viewvalue to empty/undefined and then rollback just sets it to empty. So only way i could see now is to reset the default value back on reset.

Comment: Understood, but I am back to square 1 again. What is the best method to reset all original values on a form?

Comment: The only way i could think of is the way i had in my answer. Infact i see in [angular documentation example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state) as well they do the same. If you think it will work for you i can undelete my answer.

Comment: Yes, I believe your answer will do the job. Can you post your solution again with a plunker?

Comment: Sure, Added answer with the Stack overflow demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to make the form pristine and revert back the touched state as well. You can do so by calling the special functions,  [$setPristine()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine) and [$setUntouched()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setUntouched) , on the formController. But it appears rollBackViewValue works with ngSubmit, but it is only to revertback during some action, (like esc key, another button). But if the form field has contraint errors it appears it updated viewvalue to nullify the entered value. You could try this way by resetting to default field values.

In your view:-

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
     data-ng-click="vm.reset(form)">reset</button>
```

In your controller:-

```
 var vm = this;
  var defModel = {
    fname: "Albert",
    lname: "Capone"
  };

  vm.names = angular.copy(defModel);

  vm.reset = function(form) {
    form.$rollbackViewValue();
    form.$setPristine(); //Set pristine state
    form.$setUntouched(); //Set state from touched to untouched
    vm.names = angular.copy(defModel); //reset model
  }
```

```js
var App = angular.module("App", ['App', 'ngMessages']);
App.controller('formCrtl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  var vm = this;
  var defModel = {
    fname: "Albert",
    lname: "Capone"
  };

  vm.names = angular.copy(defModel);


  vm.reset = function(form) {
    form.$rollbackViewValue(); //Probably can be removed
    form.$setPristine();
    form.$setUntouched();
   
    vm.names = angular.copy(defModel);
     
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-ng-app="App">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="formCrtl as vm">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <form name="form" novalidate="novalidate" role="form" data-ng-submit="vm.submit(form)" data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
        <!---->
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.fname.$invalid && form.fname.$touched }">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="vm.names.fname">
          <div data-ng-if="form.fname.$touched" data-ng-messages="form.fname.$error">
            <span class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">required field</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lname.$invalid && form.lname.$touched }">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="vm.names.lname">
          <div data-ng-if="form.lname.$touched" data-ng-messages="form.lname.$error">
            <span class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">required field</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 btn-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="vm.reset(form)">reset</button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't solve the problem with the ng-messages displaying on errors

Comment: @jmccommas probably i understood wrong. if you run the demo remove say fname and click on submit you will see the error right and after that click on reset, it will hide it. isn't that the issue?

Comment: The problem has something to do with the data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" we have on the form tag. If you remove it then the error messages wot=rk

Comment: ah i did not see that. I am not sure if you can use ng-modal option submit, because submit event happens on form and with this ngmodel assignment applies the submit event on input which wont work unlike the events on input element like say:- change or blur event.

Comment: I we change the form attr to data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" it works but then the reset button doesnt reset the data to pristine any more

Comment: I see it becoming pristine when you do setPristine.. I could see that when i inspect the element and also ng-message error message reverts back as well, which does not happen when you do not have the setPristine and setUntouched. Did you check my demo ?

Comment: What Im really looking for is a solid form reset function that will reset the form data to its original state.

Comment: @jmccommas if you want to set back the values then you need to do it on reset. i.e reset ngmodel. See my update. But i guess rollback does not work in your case because model value has already been updated with blur event which triggers when you click on reset

Comment: @jmccommas Also see the **[issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7017)** to support the submit event and handle form submit and update viewvalue which once rolled out will let use achieve with rollback.